# Presenting from UISearchController causes NSException

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

So I'm a bit stumped on this one. My app used to work and after going to XCode 9 this seems to have stopped working.

I have a `UITableViewController` with an attached `UISearchController` to do some very simple searching.

I've wired up my `UITableViewController` to have a `resultSearchController` field. This is how I'm configuring it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Type to search"
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

My main controller implements the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol so we're good there.

Here's the part where things explode. When someone taps on a search result this is the logic that handles what to do next:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {        
    let quoteDetailNavController = Storyboard.findViewController("Search", identifier: "QuoteDetailNav")
    let quoteDetail = (quoteDetailNavController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers[0] as! QuoteDetailViewController
    quoteDetail.quote = quoteSearchResults[indexPath.row]
    quoteDetail.delegate = self
    self.resultSearchController.present(quoteDetailNavController, animated: true) {}        
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine but when I call `self.resultSearchController.present(quoteDetailNavController, animated: true) {}` the app crashes and all I get is that an `NSException` made it happen. I've set breakpoints and tried to catch the `NSException` but all to no avail. I'm obviously doing something wrong by asking the `UISearchController` to present another controller but I can't tell what it is. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try this: `self.present(quoteDetailNavController, animated: true)`

Comment: @RichieRich if I do that, nothing happens. My main issue is that the code above was working exactly as intended and expected before. I can't figure out what changed to make it start blowing up. And I haven't found a way to intercept the `NSException` that gets thrown so I can take a looker at the deeper issue.